# A query in the proof of no retraction theorem

Tags: general-topology, analysis

No retraction theorem in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

*There is no retraction from the closed unit disc $\mathbb{D}=B(0,1)$ to its boundary $\mathbb{S}=\partial B(0,1)$*.

---

In the [proof](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_11/papers/jack.pdf) , by contradiction, suppose $f$ is a retraction above, one choose two points $\alpha,\omega \in \mathbb{S} $, and let $$A=f^{-1}(\alpha),W= f^{-1}(\omega)$$
since they each intersects $\mathbb{S} $ at only one point, we can choose a subset $E \subset \mathbb{D} - A \cup W$ who is open and connected such that the closure of $E$ contains  $\mathbb{S} $ ......

My query is why can we  guarantee that $E$ is connected?

Comment: You are removing single points from a 2D set. This does not disconnect the set. In general, to disconnect an n-dimensional set, it is necessary to remove an n-1 dimensional piece.

Comment: @JohnDouma $\mathbb{D} - A \cup W$ might be disconnected in $\mathbb{D}$

Comment: How? It is path connected so it is connected.

Comment: I'd say this "proof" goes in for some serious hand-waving. I'd advise looking at a different proof.

Answer (score 2):

The proof contains a serious gap. Quote from the paper: "The two sets $A$ and $W$ may intersect themselves, so excising them may disconnect $\mathbb{D}$. However, because they each intersect $S^1$ at only one point, excising them leaves intact some subset of $\mathbb{D}$ whose closure includes the entirety of $S^1$. Let this set be denoted by $E$. Now E is connected."

It is not at all clear what $E$ should be. Is it simply $E = \mathbb{D} \backslash (A \cup W)$? This is not sure because "excising them (i.e. $A,W$)  may disconnect $\mathbb{D}$." What else could be taken for $E$? Since it is claimed to be connected, it must be chosen as some component of $\mathbb{D} \backslash (A \cup W)$. But *no* indication is given which component.